# Show that every finite measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a metric space has a certain regularity

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a metric space and $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathcal B(E)$. Let $\mathcal E$ denote the system of all $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ such that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a closed $A\subseteq E$ and an open $C\subseteq E$ with $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ and $$\mu(C\setminus A)<\varepsilon.\tag1$$

> I want to show that $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$.

It's easy to see that every closed subset of $E$ is contained in $\mathcal E$. Moreover, if $B\in\mathcal E$, then $E\setminus B\in\mathcal E$. So, if we could show that $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal E$ implies $B:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n\in\mathcal E$, then we could conclude that $\mathcal E$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal B(E)$ containing every closed subset of $E$; hence $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$.

So, let's try to show this last property. By continuity from below, there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ with $$\mu\left(B\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^NB_n\right)<\frac\varepsilon4\tag2.$$ Since $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal E$, there are closed  $A_n\subseteq E$ and open $C_n\subseteq E$ with $A_n\subseteq B_n\subseteq C_n$ and $$\mu(C_n\setminus A_n)<\frac\varepsilon{4^n}\tag3$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Now, $$A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n$$ is closed and $$C:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n$$ is open with $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$.

How do we need to write $C\setminus A$ in order to conclude $\mu(C\setminus A)<\varepsilon$?

*Addendum*: If we would want to show that for all $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there is a *compact* $K\subseteq E$ with $K\subseteq B$ and $\mu(B\setminus K)<\varepsilon$, do we necessarily need to assume that $E$ is complete and separable?

Comment: Note that $\mu(C\backslash B) \leq \epsilon/4$, $\mu(B \backslash \cup_{i=1}^N{B_i}) \leq \epsilon/4$, and $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^N{B_i} \backslash A) \leq \sum_{i=1}^N{\mu(B_i \backslash A)} \leq \sum_{i=1}^N{\mu(B_i \backslash A_i)} \leq \epsilon/4$.

Comment: @Mindlack For $\mu(C\setminus B)$, are you using that $C\setminus B\subseteq C\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}(C_n\setminus A_n)$? This is rather elementary, but is the last inclusion really an inclusion or even an equality?